# How to query data based off of Grafana's absolute time range?

Tags: postgresql, count, grafana

I have a grafana dashboard that is connected to a PostgreSQL database. I understand how to change the absolute time range to show a time range on a graph, but am wondering if it is possible to change my query to reflect that for a total.

For example, I have a query that gets the total number of rows:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) as "Total Number of Rows:"
FROM mytable
```

Is it possible to show the total number of rows for the specified time in grafana (ex. past 30 days, past 6 hours, etc)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your query as follow:

```
SELECT
  $__time(time_column),
  count(*) as "Total Number of Rows:"
FROM
  mytable
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(time_column) 
GROUP BY time_column
```

In this way Grafana will filter using `$__timeFilter` on the specified `time_column`